# How can set by default a date field in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

I am using Ionic 3 and I am creating a table:

```
let sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS encuesta(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, sentimiento TEXT, fecha TEXT DEFAULT (datetime('now', 'localtime')))";
return this.db.executeSql(sql, []);
```

how can I make the "date" field by default a timestamp in yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss

Comment: You need a [trigger](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) for that. It can't be done in `CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: And by the way, you will be a *lot* better off using the ISO standard yyyy-mm-dd format rather than yyyy/mm/dd.

Comment: You're probably also better off not using an [AUTOINCREMENT](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) primary key; it doesn't do what the name suggests.